# Post parameters missing in django view

Tags: python, django

I have created a small web app in django, where I am sending a post request with parameters. I can clearly see those parameters present in url in django logs but in views those parameters are missing.

url: [18/Mar/2017 12:04:18] "POST /login/?email=bla@gmail.com&Password=******** HTTP/1.1" 200 20
view.py:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    for x in request.POST:
        print(x)
    email = request.POST.get("email","")
    Password = request.POST.get("Password", "")
    print("email: {0}, password:{1}".format(email, Password))
```

Comment: If the below answer helped you to resolve your question, mark it as accepted, please

Answer (score 0):

`POST` parameters are **not** passed inside the URL, but `GET` parameters do.

Try this:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    for x in request.GET:
        print(x)
    email = request.GET.get("email","")
    password = request.GET.get("Password", "")
    print("email: {0}, password:{1}".format(email, password))
```

Also, since each visit to a view is a `GET` one, then there is no reason of doing `if request.method == 'GET':`. But this is another question.

Comment: You are right that parameters in POST should not be in url. It looks like the issue is with POSTMAN chrome app which I was using to send request. On using python requests api it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your request isnt POST, 'cause the request parameters are being passed in yout GET context. Try to check if your `<form method='POST'>` its correctly formed to send a post, and your view function accepting just POST methods, by passing:

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def myview(request):
```